# each event in table 1 has timestamp. Find all transactions in table 2 that started before and finished after

Tags: mysql, sql, select, timestamp, data-manipulation

I am looking for a SELECT statement that takes Tables 1 and 2 and generates Table 3 with the following properties.

Table 1: event_id | customer_id | timestamp
Table 2: transaction_id | time_started | time_finished

(Desired) Table 3: for each customer, specifies all transactions that were active when the customer performed an event described in table 1. The transaction is considered active if it started before an event and finished after it. The format of table 3:

customer_id | transaction_id

UPD:
time_finished is actually stored in another table (Table 4) in the following way:

event_code | transaction_id | timestamp

where event_code = "finished" corresponds to the 'finish' event.

Comment: Where is your attempted code?

Comment: So what does time_finished in table2 do?

Comment: there is no time_finished in table2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 select t1.customer_id, t2.transaction_id
   from table1 t1 join table2 t2 
     on t1.timestamp between t2.time_started and t2.time_finished
```

**Edit: new table** I'm guessing table2.transaction_id is equal to table4.transaction_id

```
select t1.customer_id, t2.transaction_id
       from table1 t1 join table2 t2 
         on t1.timestamp >= t2.time_started
       join table4 t4 on t2.transaction_id = t4.transaction_id
        and t1.timestamp <= t4.timestamp
        and t4.event_code = 'finished'
```

Comment: Many thanks @vercelli! I just realized that time_finished is stored in another table (Table 4) in the following way: event_code | transaction_id | timestamp. event_code = "finished" corresponds to the 'finish' event. How should I then modify the code?